# Supabase API, is basic authorization an option

Tags: basic-authentication, supabase, http-auth

I'm new to Supabase, but it looks very nice and promising for many future projects.
In this case I'm trying to use it to store web hook requests from another system - this system, however, only supports sending web hook requests with Basic Authorization header as means of auth and from what I can tell, Supabase doesn't support this, only apikey.

Does anyone know if the Supabase API can we used with Basic Authorization header?

Answer (score 1):

In order to receive webhooks, you need a backend. Supabase provides [Edge Functions](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/functions), but it only supports receiving POST requests at the moment, so if you want to receive GET request webhooks, you might want to use other functions providers like [vercel](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions#serverless-functions).

Whatever backend provider you choose, verifying the webhook request should be possible. Once requests are verified, the results can be stored on Supabase database using our client library.